# specified authorisation in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, adventureworks

I have a sample shop database(AdventureWorks) and I want to grant every costumer to edit themselve's sales.So It seems I can't use views because view must be created for every costumer

Comment: Does every customer have their own database user? Then you can created a view that includes the current database user. Another option is to use [row level security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

1. A view like Aleksandr suggested:

   ```
   CREATE VIEW myview
   WITH (security_barrier = true) AS
      SELECT ...
      FROM atable
      WHERE customer = current_user
   WITH CHECK OPTION;
   ```

   Such views can also be modified in PostgreSQL
2. Use [Row Level Security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html). A simple example:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE atable ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

   CREATE POLICY xy ON atable
      FOR ALL TO PUBLIC
      USING (customer = current_user)
      WITH CHECK (customer = current_user);
   ```

You see that both examples hinge on the current database user; this is the simplest case.

If you don't have separate database users for each customers, you need something else to identify a customer inside the database. One frequently used method is to use a *database parameter*: the application sets something like

```
SET myapp.user = 'Customer1';  -- or use "application_name"
```

The drawback with this is that such a setting can be overridden by the user, who can subvert security in that way. If you want to avoid that, write a small C extension that defines a proper parameter that can only be set by superusers or that cannot be changes once it has been set.

Comment: Don't you need the `with check` option on the view?

Comment: I wrote only a `SELECT` policy, where `WITH CHECK` is not necessary. But you are right, I should expand it a little.

Comment: I was actually referring to the view, not the policy ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah, you are right. I also forgot `security_barrier`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use conditions for views as well as for selection, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
Id INTEGER auto_increment,
CreatedUserLogin VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Product VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE VIEW vOrders AS
SELECT Id, CreatedUserLogin, Product FROM Products;

SELECT * FROM vOrders WHERE CreatedUser = CURRENT_USER();
```

The CURRENT_USER function will return the login of the current user, and using it you can get his orders, or instead of the function, you can use a variable that you will pass from outside.

Upd:
For postgres use:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (Id integer, CreatedUserLogin varchar(100), Product varchar(10));

CREATE VIEW vOrders AS SELECT id, CreatedUserLogin, Product FROM Orders;

INSERT INTO Orders (Id, CreatedUserLogin, Product) VALUES (1, (SELECT CURRENT_USER), 'TEST');

SELECT * FROM vOrders WHERE CreatedUserLogin = (SELECT CURRENT_USER);
```

P.S. Do not use * in your queries, rather explicitly specify the attributes. This will help avoid some problems.

Comment: `(select current_user)` can be simplified to `current_user`